# Get name of Farm account using Powershell

Tags: powershell, security

How can I get the name of the Farm account ?   I can see it listed in Get-SPManagedAccount, but do not see any properties on the SPManagedAccount objects to be able to dynamically filter by and determine if it's the farm administrator.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `(Get-SPFarm).DefaultServiceAccount.Name` should give you the Farm Account

Answer (score 7):

This will give you the Farm Administrators:

```
$ca = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::AdministrationService.WebApplications | Select -First 1
$root = $ca.Sites["/"].RootWeb
$grp = $root.SiteGroups["Farm Administrators"]
$grp.Users
```

and

`Get-SPManagedAccount` will give you managed accounts

There should only be the farm admin common in these two groups

Comment: Another more "powershell'is" way to find CA `Get-SPWebApplication -IncludeCentralAdministration | ? IsAdministrationWebApplication`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to PowerShell, SharePoint Timer Service runs under farm account. Check it out and you get farm account

Comment: Do you have some steps to check `SharePoint Timer Service`, if so can you please share it as part of an answer.

Comment: You can get the account for the SharePoint Timer Service as well using PowerShell, namely via WMI (as Get-Service does not provide this info, see: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/02/15/the-scripting-wife-uses-powershell-to-find-service-accounts/): (Get-WmiObject Win32_Service | ? { $_.Name -eq 'SPTimerV4' }).StartName

Answer (score -1):

To change the farm account you need to use stsadm, still.

stsadm –o updatefarmcredentials –userlogin DOMAIN\username –password password

Comment: The question is not about how to change farm account

Answer (score -2):

This is what I used to change the farm account

```
Get-SPManagedAccount

New-SPManagedAccount

Remove-SPManagedAccount

Set-SPManagedAccount
```

Comment: Can you please add more details regarding what parameters to pass